# Calling function from one script attached to multiple gameObjects

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a single script that is attached to multiple gameObjects. I have another script from which I call a function to the first script. Issue is that the function does not get called. I think it is not able to find the script attached in multiple gameObjects.

Script_1

```
public void CallMyFunction(){
  Debug.Log("CALL");
}
```

Script_2

```
void CallingScripts()
{
   foreach(var scr in GetComponentsInChildren<Script_1>()) {
             scr .CallMyFunction();
         }
}
```

How do I solve this?

Comment: You just can create a list in one of the manager type classes like **GameManager** and then create **List<ClassNameToCall>** and in awake function of scripts you want to call  subscribe to **GameManager** class.

Comment: Are all of them children of the script this is attached to? And are they all active in the hierarchy?

Answer (score 0):

I created an array and then added all the script instances in that array. After that I was able to call it.

```
private Script_1[] scr;

void Start()
{
     scr= FindObjectsOfType<Script_1>();
            foreach (Script_1 scrs in scr)
            {
                scrs.CallMyFunction();
            }
}
```

Comment: `FindObjectsOfType` (looks for the instances in the entire Scene hierarchy) does something completely different to your original `GetComponentsInChildren` (looks for the instances only in the hierarchy below this object) ...